# Detecting CListCtrl column resizing

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a pretty simple dialog containing basically a `CListCtrl` in report mode with several columns and with a header.

Now I need to detect when the user has resized a column and I hoped that `OnHdnChanged` would be called each time the user has resized a column.

Amoungst others I have this in my message map, `IDC_LIST1` being the id of the list control.

```
ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_LIST1, OnItemchangedList)
ON_NOTIFY(HDN_ENDTRACKW, IDC_LIST1, OnHdnChanged)
```

`OnHdnChanged` function:

```
void CMyDlg::OnHdnChanged(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
  ...
  *pResult = 0;
}

void CSanDlg::OnItemchangedList(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
  ...
```

`OnItemchangedList` is called when exepected, but `OnHdnChanged` is not. I supposed `OnHdnChanged` is not called because the header control's parent is not my dialog but it's the list control.

Does anybody know what I can do?

Answer (score 3):

I was just looking at this [old article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/866/Using-the-Header-Control), which suggests changing the `ON_NOTIFY` to `ON_NOTIFY(HDN_ENDTRACKW, 0, OnHdnChanged)`, since the control ID of the header control seems always to be 0.

I don't know if that's still true, but it's worth checking.

---

Edit: Updating based on responding comment. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999381/mfc-clistctrl-right-click-on-header?rq=1)'s another suggestion I came across, which is subclassing the `CListCtrl` and handling the notification there. Presumably that handler could delegate actual handling logic to its parent.

Comment: The explanation in the old article you mention sounds good, but unfortunately it doesn't work here, `OnHdnChanged` is still not called. The control id of the header control is still 0, I've checked that with wincheat (similar to the old spy++).

Comment: I also thought about subclassing the CListCtrl, but I'd like to avoid that as it's a bit of an overkill. But if there is no other way, I might do this. In the meantime I'll wait for some more answers. Anyway +1

Comment: 1st part of your answer is already sufficient. There is no need to subclass the control. I have just verified. BTW: The same code is added by the dialog editor if you interactively add a handler for `HDN_ENDTRACK`.